# Aplicación en .Net sin instalar .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Cuando desarrollas una aplicación en Visual Studio con c# y WPF ¿es siempre necesario instalar .Net Framework en el ordenador cliente?

La instalación de .Net lleva mas de 5 minutos en el mejor de los casos. No entiendo si quiero instalar en un W7 mi aplicación por qué tengo que estar 5min en instalar .Net ya que ninguna aplicación de otros antes me ha obligado a instalarlo.

¿Hay forma de usar una aplicación desarrollada en c# con WPF que no necesite .Net para funcionar?(O que necesite una versión mas liviana ya que no es para desarrolladores).

Comment: Es como comenta @Asier. Pero te pasara lo mismo con Java por ejemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buenas jooooooooota,

`Net Framework` es necesario para ejecutar todas las aplicaciones desarrolladas en `.Net`, cuando tu dices `ya que ninguna aplicación de otros antes me ha obligado a instalarlo` será que las aplicaciones que has instalado están desarrolladas con un Framework que ya viene instalado en el Sistema Operativo. Si usas las últimas versiones de `Net Framework` siempre te va a pedir instalar-lo, si no lo está, para poder ejecutar esas aplicaciones.

La solución a tus problemas seria usar una versión de `Net Framework` compatible con los sistemas operativos que vas a instalar, puedes consultar las compatibilidades [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx).

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: También puede ser que las aplicaciones a las que se refiere, que dice que no lo obligan a instalar el .net framework, no sean aplicaciones .net.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres ejecutar aplicaciones .NET en un Windows 7 será necesario que el equipo tenga instalada la version de .NET Framework que utilice la aplicación.

Si quieres evitar tener que instalar el Framework la opción más sencilla es desarrollar la aplicación con la versión 3.5 del Framework que ya viene incluida con el sistema operativo en Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Si amigo `El .Net Framework` version XXX es necesario de instalar a menos que ya lo tengas en el ordenador. ya que en el Framework estan librerias que tu programa llama y utiliza. y si la computadora donde la vas a instalar no lo tiene presentaria problemas, bueno windows para evitar esto, te obliga a descargar el framework necesario. por eso al momento de desarrollar tu escoges cual version del mismo quieres